# Bug or feature: stored procedure that returns multiple rows with same primary key value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

During developing an application with LINQ to SQL, I found that when a stored procedure returns multiple distinct rows with same primary key then LINQ will make the complete list object same. For example, If I have the following table,

```
ID  Name  Salary
--  ----  -----
 1    A     20
 2    B     200
 3    C     30
 4    D     520
```

and my stored procedure returns all rows except with same primary key,

```
ID  Name  Salary
--  ----  -----
 1    A     20
 1    B     200
 1    C     30
 1    D     520
```

then  linq will bind these rows as,

```
ID  Name  Salary
--  ----  -----
 1    A     20
 1    A     20
 1    A     20
 1    A     20
```

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: I am asking that whether this is a Linq feature or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I'd say that's a bug in your stored procedure. Why would you return duplicate primary keys?

Comment: I am reusing the a class which contain the same table fields except for primary key. That's why, I hard code the primary key in my SP. I will create a new class for this but I only need to confirm that whether this is a feature or a bug.

Comment: show th code of your sproc. I hardly believe such bug can be ship by MS

Comment: @SteveB, The code is auto generated by LINQ designer. BTW, If I return the different primary key values then the same code provide intended result. You can also test this scenario very easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug it is a feature. Both entity framework and Linq-to-Sql demands uniquely identified entity and entity with each unique key can be loaded only once so when you return multiple records representing same entity type with same key only first record is materialized into entity and this entity is used for representation of all other records with the same key (so it will not only return the same data but the same reference to the entity). It is called identity map and it is key feature of ORM tools.